# Iterating through a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have a `Document` which `has_many` `Companies` through `Companydocs`. And vice versa, there is a `Company` which `has_many` `Documents` through `Companydocs`. This all works fine. Now I have a documents index view where I show all documents and a column for each company with a true or false value if that document applies for the company.

I can get all `document.company_ids` but then I don't get the false companies, only the true companies, so I should iterate through all companies first:

```
%table
  %tr
    %td Document
    %td Company A
    %td Company B
  - @documents.each do |doc|
    %tr
      %td= doc.name
      - Company.all.each do |company|
        - if company has document for this company
          "true"
        - else
          "false"
```

How should I write the pseudo code `if company has document for this company`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method, like this:

```
if company.documents.include?(doc)
```

Also, I strongly recommend pre-loading companies (along with associated documents) in controller, so you could avoid multiple SQL queries:

```
@companies = Company.includes(:documents)
```

and in view:

```
- @companies.each do |company|
```